# How to test custom created model of tensorflow on Movidius?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I started running movidius on my machine. It is working fine with the Inception model describe here
https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/TensorFlow.html

But when i am trying to create graph file of my own custom trained model using given command in the above link:

```
mvNCCompile hehehe/model.ckpt.meta -in image_tensor -on detection_classes -s12
```

i am getting this error:
[image: error mesg]

So i tried to print the detail of input node got this one
[image: input name detail]

So what is the mistake i am making here? How to get absolute value of placeholder?

this is my graph structure on tensorboard
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are still working on custom created model, as they have told me to give my model

https://ncsforum.movidius.com/discussion/322/tensorflow-support-on-ncs#latest